# npm run script failing to compile sass

Tags: npm, sass, node-sass, npm-scripts

So, it seems after updating brackets.io, I can no longer run a script that compiles my sass code using node-sass. I'm still new to this so bear with me.

Here is the error file when I try to npm run the script:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Tad\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'compile:sass' ]
2 info using npm@6.0.0
3 info using node@v8.11.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'precompile:sass', 'compile:sass', 'postcompile:sass' ]
5 info lifecycle natours@1.0.0~precompile:sass: natours@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle natours@1.0.0~compile:sass: natours@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle natours@1.0.0~compile:sass: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle natours@1.0.0~compile:sass: PATH: C:\Users\Tad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Tad\Desktop\starter\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Users\Tad\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle natours@1.0.0~compile:sass: CWD: C:\Users\Tad\Desktop\starter
10 silly lifecycle natours@1.0.0~compile:sass: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w' ]
11 silly lifecycle natours@1.0.0~compile:sass: Returned: code: 3221225786  signal: null
12 info lifecycle natours@1.0.0~compile:sass: Failed to exec compile:sass script
13 verbose stack Error: natours@1.0.0 compile:sass: `node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w`
13 verbose stack Exit status 3221225786
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Tad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:283:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Tad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid natours@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Tad\Desktop\starter
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Tad\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "compile:sass"
18 verbose node v8.11.1
19 verbose npm  v6.0.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 3221225786
22 error natours@1.0.0 compile:sass: `node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w`
22 error Exit status 3221225786
23 error Failed at the natours@1.0.0 compile:sass script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 3221225786, true ]
```

And when I tried to npm rebuild node-sass -force:

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\MSBuild \ToolsVersions" /s /reg:32 
gyp ERR! stack 'reg' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
gyp ERR! stack operable program or batch file. 
gyp ERR! stack gyp ERR! stack Can't find "msbuild.exe". Do you have Microsoft Visual Studio C++  2008+ installed? 
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Tad\Desktop\starter\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\bui ld.js:138:25 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:282:5) 
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13) 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7) 
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16) 
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_proces s.js:209:5) 
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601 
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Tad\\Desktop\ \starter\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--lib sass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library=" 
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Tad\Desktop\starter\node_modules\node-sass 
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.1 
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2 
gyp ERR! not ok Build failed with error code:
```

I have MS VS 2008+, and I downloaded the MS Build Tools 2015 thinking that may help, but it still doesn't work.

Also, if there is no easy fix, do I just remove node-sass from my project manually and then reinstall it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happen to me once on office workstation, and if I remember correctly this command did it for me

`npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`

This is the github issue page for windows build trouble https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2074

Comment: Thanks. I will check this out. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you so much. After installing windows-build-tools I ran `npm rebuild node-sass` and my script starting working again. No clue why this started happening after the brackets update, but I'm glad it's fixed.

Comment: @Outrunx glad it help. Windows build is a bit tricky afterall. I have faced a couple not working lib when build in windows compared to unix counterpart. But it getting more stable IMHO in recent version. May I ask you to mark my answer as accepted if it help.

Answer (score -2):

npm install --global --production windows-build-tools

Comment: This answer duplicates an existing answer, without contributing substantially more detail.